Removing duplicates from Bigquery JSON String
I am querying from the BigQuery table (cost data exported table). In Which I am getting different labels for a single resource. So it's making it difficult while processing.
so I tried to merge all the different labels for a resource. But it ended up in duplicates.
[{"key":"label1","value":"test"},{"key":"label2","value":"vm"},{"key":"label1","value":"test"},{"key":"label2","value":"vm"},{"key":"label1","value":"test"},{"key":"label2","value":"vm"},{"key":"label1","value":"test"},{"key":"label2","value":"vm"}

As mentioned above it gives the duplicates.
I want to remove duplicates and merge unique values.
it's my query.
    SELECT
        billing_account_id,
        service.id AS service_id,
        sku.id AS sku_id,
        FORMAT_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d', usage_start_time) AS usage_date,
        location.location AS location,
        project.id AS project_id,
        project.number AS project_number,
        resource.name AS resource_name,
        resource.global_name AS res_global_name,
        TO_JSON_STRING(ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(labels)) AS labels
    from 
        ${TABLE_NAME}
    where 
        usage_start_time>=${time} and usage_end_time<=${time}
    group by 
        billing_account_id, 
        service_id,
        sku_id,
        usage_date,
        location,
        project_id,
        project_number,
        resource_name,
        res_global_name


I think this should work for you
with base as (

select 'dimension' as dimension, '[{"key":"label1","value":"test"},{"key":"label2","value":"vm"},{"key":"label1","value":"test"},{"key":"label2","value":"vm"},{"key":"label1","value":"test"},{"key":"label2","value":"vm"},{"key":"label1","value":"test"},{"key":"label2","value":"vm"}]' as label

union all 

select 'dimension1' as dimension, '[{"key":"label1","value":"test"},{"key":"label2","value":"vm"},{"key":"label1","value":"test"},{"key":"label2","value":"vm"},{"key":"label1","value":"test"},{"key":"label2","value":"vm"},{"key":"label1","value":"test"},{"key":"label2","value":"vm"}]' 

union all

select 'dimension2' as dimension, '[{"key":"label1","value":"test"},{"key":"label2","value":"vm"},{"key":"label1","value":"test"},{"key":"label2","value":"vm"},{"key":"label1","value":"test"},{"key":"label2","value":"vm"},{"key":"label1","value":"test"},{"key":"label2","value":"vm"}]' 

)

, array_broken as (

select

  dimension,
  json_extract_array(label) as label_new

from base

)

select 

  distinct
  array_broken.dimension,
  json_extract(jsons, '$.key') as keys,
  json_extract(jsons, '$.value') as values,

from array_broken
cross join unnest(array_broken.label_new) as jsons

Now the code explanation:
First thing first, you have an ARRAY stored as a STRING that you need to break down first. Based on here, you just give the JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY function your STRING, and it does its magic for you.
select

  dimension,
  json_extract_array(label) as label_new

from base

Now you have a JSON stored in an ARRAY. First you need to UNNEST the array so you have it flattened. And finally using this, you just need to use JSON_EXTRACT function and give it the json path.
select 

  distinct
  array_broken.dimension,
  json_extract(jsons, '$.key') as keys,
  json_extract(jsons, '$.value') as values,

from array_broken
cross join unnest(array_broken.label_new) as jsons

This does what you need it to do. However, be careful that there might be edge cases, depending on your data, and you need to adapt the query.
